# Chrome extension sandbox with jQuery

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension ATM.

However, it provides the following error:

> There were warnings when trying to install this extension: 'content_security_policy' is only allowed for extensions and legacy packaged apps, but this is a packaged app.

I googled to find what the error means and came across the concept of **sandbox**.

However, after adding a **sandbox**, my app still does not seem to work.

Here is the code:

**manifest.json:**

```
{
  "name": "Name",
  "description": "Name",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "0.1",
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  },
  "permissions": ["", "storage", ""],
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "sandbox": {
   "pages": ["sandbox.html"]
 },
  "update_url": "http://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://js.live.net; object-src 'self'"

}
```

**register.html:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap.min.css" >
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/login.css">
        <script src="assets/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="register.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/wl.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe src="sandbox.html"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

**sandbox.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>    
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <input  id="signin" tabindex="4" value="Sign in">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**background.js (fired on page create):**

```
....
    chrome.app.window.create(
      "register.html",
      {  width: 500,
         height: 400,
         frame: 'chrome'
      },
      function(appWin) {}
    );
...
```

**register.js (removed any keys and on init):**

```
...
  $('#signin').click(function() {
    WL.init({
        client_id: "",
        redirect_uri: "",
        response_type: ""
    });
    WL.login({
          scope: ["", ""]
      });

    return false;

  });
...
```

I am not sure where I am wrong. I tried to follow the sample by google extension.

Thanks a lot for any help or just reading this!

First question here! My teammates were doing this earlier and told me to do this part!